# If $f :[-7,0]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[-7,0]$ and differentiable on $(-7,0)$ such that $f(-7)=3$ find $f(-1)+ f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> If $f :[-7,0]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[-7,0]$ and differentiable on $(-7,0)$ such that $f(-7)=3$ and $f'(x)\leq 2$ for all $x$, find the possible range of $f(-1)+ f(0)$.

My attempt:

Given the  inequality I got $f(x)<2x+C$ by integrating both sides, with $C$ being $11$. Thus substituting in $f(-1)+ f(0)$ I got it's less that $11$, however, my book says this is wrong

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You cannot find the exact value of $f(1)+f(-1)$. The question is wrong.

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is $[-7,0]$ then $f(1)$ is not defined.

Comment: @geetha290krm, sorry, imeant range of the sum

Comment: @David, sorry, typo

Comment: It's easy to envisage many different answers even restricting $f$ to linear.

Comment: @StinkingBishop you cannot change $f(1)$ by $f(0)$ because we dont know if this is the correct statement of the question.

Comment: @Masacroso The OP changed it at *one* place but forgot to change it everywhere else. Please check out the history of the post.

Comment: @StinkingBishop right. I undone to your edit.

Comment: I think what you did wrong is: (a) $f(x)<2x+C$ should be $\le$. (b) $C$ is not $11$, it is $17$. (c) You incorrectly substituted $-1$ and $0$ (or maybe even substituted $1$), and (d) Unless you know Lebesgue integration (i.e. if you only know Riemann integration) you cannot integrate $f'(x)$ as you don't know that it is integrable. But you can still use MVT.

Comment: And (e) Really if you want to find the range, you need to not only find *necessary* conditions but also *sufficient* conditions for the value to be in the range. Say, if your calculation *was* correct, you have still only proven that $f(-1)+f(0)\le 11$ (or whatever is the correct value) but you have not proven that *every* value in $(-\infty, 11]$ is a potential value of $f(-1)+f(0)$ for some function $f$.

Comment: Does your book say that the range is $(-\infty, 32]$ ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop, -infity, 20

Comment: @StinkingBishop, why won't  rienmann 8ntegratiom work here

Comment: This looks like a typo. If it was $f(-7) = -3$ instead of $f(7)=3$, then the logic above exactly gives $9+11 = 20$ as the upper bound, which is the book answer. There must be a typo.

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever For example, the derivative may be unbounded. (From below, in this case.) Only bounded functions are Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer *If* it was that, then I drop my part (b) above. $C$ would then  be $11$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Right, the basic point is that the OP can get the upper bound from their working and now needs to work just a little harder to show that $(-\infty,20)$ is the answer, using appropriate linear functions. I have voted up your comment highlighting this.

Answer (score 2):

I will repeat what I said in my comments. I think what you did wrong is:

(a) $f(x)<2x+C$ should be $\le$.

(b) $C$ is not $11$, it is $17$. If $f(x)=2x+C$, then $f(-7)=2(-7)+C=C-14=3$ so $C=17$. However, it might be that there was a typo in the question and if $f(-7)=-3$  then $C=11$ is correct.

(c) You incorrectly substituted $−1$ and $0$ (or maybe $-1$ and $1$) in $f(x)=2x+11$.

(d) Unless you know Lebesgue integration (i.e. if you only know Riemann integration) you cannot integrate $f′(x)$ as you don't know that it is Riemann-integrable (E.g. it may be unbounded.) But you can still use [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) (MVT).

(e) Really if you want to find the range, you need to not only find *necessary* conditions but also *sufficient* conditions for the value to be in the range. Say, if your calculation was correct, you have still only proven that $f(−1)+f(0)\le 11$
(or whatever is the correct value) but you have not proven that every value in $(-\infty,11]$ is a potential value of $f(−1)+f(0)$ for some function $f$.

---

So, now that we know that your solution is deficient, what should the correct solution look like? (All that follows is assuming we've corrected the question to state $f(-7)=-3$.)

First of all, the conditions of the problem are sufficient to apply MVT on $[-7,-1]$ and $[-7,0]$.

This means that there exists $\xi\in[-7,-1]$ such that $f(-1)-f(-7)=f'(\xi)(-1-(-7))=6f'(\xi)\le 6\times 2=12$. Thus, $f(-1)\le f(-7)+12=-3+12=9$

This also means that there exists $\omega\in[-7,0]$ such that $f(0)-f(-7)=f'(\omega)(0-(-7))=7f'(\omega)\le 7\times 2=14$. Thus, $f(0)\le f(-7)+14=-3+14=11$.

Finally, if $f(-1)\le 9$ and $f(0)\le 11$, then $f(-1)+f(0)\le 9+11=20$. Thus $f(-1)+f(0)\in(-\infty, 20]$.

Now, let $b\in (-\infty, 20]$, i.e. $b\le 20$. Can we have a function which satisfies the conditions of the problem and also has $f(-1)+f(0)=b$? The answer is yes. Look for the function of the form $f(x)=a(x+7)-3$ which is linear and $f(-7)=-3$. Then, $f(-1)+f(0)=6a-3+7a-3=13a-6=b$. Solve for $a$: $a=\frac{b+6}{13}$. And, since $b\le 20$, we have $a\le\frac{20+6}{13}=2$. On the other hand, $f'(x)=a$ so $f'(x)\le 2$ too and so the function $f$ satisfies the conditions of the problem.

The conclusion is that $(-\infty, 20]$ is the exact range of values of $f(-1)+f(0)$ for those functions that satisfy the conditions of the problem.